# Can a GNU Make function find libraries?

Tags: search, makefile

Is there a simple way within GNU make to construct an if-block that can identify whether a library (or even better, a header file!) is installed in the standard search directories?

I have a fairly simple set of unit tests, built by a short Makefile (no autoconf, CMake, etc.), which I want to be able to bundle up an build on multiple platforms.  Some of these platforms are centrally managed clusters.
One of my tests depends on a user-installable library (libmemcached), which may not be available on the clusters.

I can do this sort of thing by constructing a CMake or autoconf system, but the project (four unit tests and a "library" of seven classes), just doesn't seem big enough to warrant it.  The picture I have in my head is something like

```
ifneq (,$(lib-exists -lmemcached))
  LIBSRC += MemCDIndex.cc
  SRC += memcd-index.cc
  LDLIBS += -lmemcached
endif
```

where LIBSRC and SRC are defined in my Makefile, listing the associated source files, and "lib-exists" is the function I'm trying to find.

Comment: If the library installs a `pkg-config`/`.pc` file then you can ask `pkg-config` whether it exists and use that in a make conditional.

Comment: Sounds like: I want to get the features from Autoconf or CMake but don't want to use it. There is a reason these tools exist and are used. If it does not fit your needs, you might want to use some local variables you set by hand. Or create a tiny Autoconf project, add the features you want to check and examine the generated configure script. Maybe you can borrow parts of the script.

Comment: Thank you both!  As my situation is limited to Unix-ish systems (Linux and MacOSX), I will look at pkg-config in more detail.  You're right about wanting this feature from Autoconf/CMake, but not adopting a full extra layer.